# Does PHPUnit have some inbuilt recursive array comparison function?

Tags: php, unit-testing, recursion, multidimensional-array, phpunit

Some of the testing I will need to do will require comparing a known array with the result I am getting from the functions I will be running.

For comparing arrays recursively:

- Does PHPUnit have an inbuilt function?
- Does someone here have some code they have constructed to share?
- Will this be something I will have to construct on my own?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it does. [`assertEquals()` and `assertNotEquals()` documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals).

Specifically:

> ## assertEquals()
>
> ```
> assertEquals(mixed $expected, mixed $actual[, string $message = ''])
> ```
>
> Reports an error identified by `$message` if the two variables `$expected` and `$actual` are not equal.
>
> `assertNotEquals()` is the inverse of this assertion and takes the same arguments.

Test Code:

```
public function testArraysEqual() {
    $arr1 = array( 'hello' => 'a', 'goodbye' => 'b');
    $arr2 = array( 'hello' => 'a', 'goodbye' => 'b');

    $this->assertEquals($arr1, $arr2);
}

public function testArraysNotEqual() {
    $arr1 = array( 'hello' => 'a', 'goodbye' => 'b');
    $arr2 = array( 'hello' => 'b', 'goodbye' => 'a');

    $this->assertNotEquals($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Here is the code for out of order aLists:

```
public function testArraysEqualReverse() {
    $arr1 = array( 'hello' => 'a', 'goodbye' => 'b');
    $arr2 = array( 'goodbye' => 'b', 'hello' => 'a');

    $this->assertEquals($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

This test fails:

```
public function testArraysOutOfOrderEqual() {
    $arr1 = array( 'a', 'b');
    $arr2 = array( 'b', 'a');

    $this->assertEquals($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

With message:

```
Failed asserting that 
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => a
)
 is equal to 
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

Comment: Is this a function that requires the arrays being compared to be in exactly the same order key for key?

Comment: So if I want to test an out of order array against a known good, I will have to make sure the keys match, but that is the only caveat? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @wilmoore: You sure? `array_values` will re-index an array and strip any array keys, but it won't re-order numeric arrays.

Comment: @Mark, just noting that the answer was updated removing the `array_values` portion.

Comment: The question was about recursive comparison. Your example provides 1-dimensional arrays only. So the question stands open - does asserEqual() support __multi-dimentional__ array comparision? And the answer is YES.

Answer (score 4):

@wilmoore

```
$array1 = array('hi','hi2');
$array2 = array('hi2','hi');
$this->assertEquals(array_values($array1), array_values($array2));
```

Will fail.

@Ben Dauphinee

It might be worth looking at `assertContains(mixed $needle, array $haystack)` but you would have to loop through both arrays and compare each element with the other array to ensure it contained all the required elements and no others, this however wouldn't account for an array containing two identical elements

```
$array1 = array('hi','hi2','hi');
$array2 = array('hi2','hi');
```

would pass in this case

It also doesn't account for any further recursion which would probably be quite complicated to deal with.

Depending on the complexity might just be easier in the long run to implement your own assert function.

Comment: indeed, the `array_values` technique will not work. It was years ago when I posted so I don't quite recall why this was asserted.

Answer (score 2):

The `assertEqual` method head looks like this:

```
public static function assertEquals($expected, $actual, $message = '', $delta = 0, $maxDepth = 10, $canonicalize = FALSE, $ignoreCase = FALSE)
```

If the canonicalize parameter is set to true the arrays will be run through `sort()` first, this is usable if the keys are arbitrary and only the values matters.

However after looking over the array comparator code, the `assertEqual` actually does not care about the order of an associated array :) It will simply look for the expected key in the result array, and then compare the values of those keys.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with some generated arrays with keys - I ended up passing both the expected array and the array being tested through ksort before calling assertEquals. This doesn't work on recursive arrays, though.

```
$expectedArray = array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 0);
$array = array('bar' => 0, 'foo' => 1);

ksort($expectedArray);
ksort($array);

var_dump($expectedArray); // outputs array('bar' => 0, 'foo' => 1);
var_dump($array); // outputs array('bar' => 0, 'foo' => 1);

$this->assertEquals($expectedArray, $array); // passes
```